# Postgresql UUID[] to Cassandra: Conversion Error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, spark-cassandra-connector

It gives me java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.util.UUID; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;

My job reads data from a PostgreSQL table that contains columns of `user_ids uuid[]` type, so that I'm getting the error above when I'm trying to save data on Cassandra.

However, the creation of this same table on Cassandra works fine!  `user_ids list<text>`.

I can't change the type on the source table, because I'm reading data from a legacy system.

I've been looking at point printed on log, on class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils.scala

````
case StringType =>
      (array: Object) =>
        array.asInstanceOf[Array[java.lang.String]]
          .map(UTF8String.fromString)```
````

[image: Debug view]

---

Stacktrace

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.util.UUID; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$14.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:443)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$14.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:442)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$makeGetter$13$$anonfun$18.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:472)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$makeGetter$13$$anonfun$18.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:472)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$nullSafeConvert(JdbcUtils.scala:482)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$makeGetter$13.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:470)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$makeGetter$13.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:469)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anon$1.getNext(JdbcUtils.scala:330)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anon$1.getNext(JdbcUtils.scala:312)
at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:32)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation$$anonfun$1$$anon$1.hasNext(InMemoryRelation.scala:133)
at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIteratorAsValues(MemoryStore.scala:215)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1038)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1029)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:969)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1029)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:760)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:334)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:285)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Can try to cast array -> array.asInstanceOf[Array[UUID]] then try to cast this new array to String i.e. newArray.map(_.toString)

Answer (score 0):

Please look at datatype support in [CQL](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cql_data_types_c.html) here.

You should have created `list<uuid>` instead of `list<text>` in your table schema. The Java driver can't handle this conversion automatically.

If you want to use `text` instead, please cast it to String in your application before sending it to driver.

Comment: Thanks! I'll do it, but I was trying to use just one Job to do this conversions, and that type was created automatically by the driver. It's sad but I'll must to write a specific job for that table. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

the value you have stored user_id in database is of type UUID ,the same type in java is of type java.util.UUID .

so instead of using java.lang.String,you should use java.util.UUID array or list and before storing in cassandra uuid_obj.toString() to store in Cassandra.